# Decryption of something encrypted with Java

Tags: apex, java, decrypt

I have a little problem. I want to decrypt a Text that I encrypted with a method written in Eclipse using Java. When i try to decrypt it using my IV and my key, i get an error (System.SecurityException: update() failed).
I guess there is a problem with the format of the key or something, but i actually don't know what to do now and would be happy if someone could help me.